# user input validation Lazarus Mac

Tags: macos, lazarus, freepascal

I have a Windows Lazarus app i am converting to Mac.  On windows I use OnExit from a textbox to validate user input.  Incorrect data, such as an illegal date results or a must enter field not having any data results in the user being returned to the error-causing textbox through the use of `.SetFocus`, e.g.

```
if length(Edit1.Text) = 0 then
   Edit1.SetFocus;
```

This works in Windows but not on the Mac.  My research showed that this problem has occurred on unix machines and could be controlled with `Application.ProcessMessages`. How do I make Returning to the offending TextBox work on a Mac?

Comment: Generally this is a poor way to validate. My advice would be to avoid forcing focus like that.